# dropping column using pandas-drop()-function not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file with time series data. From this file I want to remove the first column (containing the dates).

However, the following code:

```
from pandas import read_csv

dataset = read_csv('USrealGDPGrowthPred_Quarterly.txt', header=0)
dataset.drop('DATE', axis=1)
```

results in this error message:

```
ValueError: labels ['DATE'] not contained in axis
```

But: the label is contained in the file, as you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

What is going on here? How can I get rid of that column?

UPDATE:

the following code:

```
dataset = read_csv('USrealGDPGrowthPred_Quarterly.txt', header=0, sep='\t')
dataset.drop('DATE', axis=1)    
print(dataset.head(5))
```

does not result in an error message but doesn't drop the column either. The data looks like nothing happened.

Comment: What is `df.columns.tolist()`? If there is no `DATE` column because `index`, need `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: dataset.columns.tolist() gives nothing

Comment: I think `print (df.columns.tolist())`

Comment: the output is:['DATE\tA191RI1Q225SBEA\tA191RL1Q225SBEA\tMABMM301USQ657S']

Comment: I think a [mcve] would help. No pictures please.

Comment: Ah, you have a TSV, so please use `df = read_csv('USrealGDPGrowthPred_Quarterly.txt', header=0, sep='\t')`

Comment: ok ... I'm not getting an error message anymore ... but the column is not dropped either

Comment: Or use `df = df.read_table('USrealGDPGrowthPred_Quarterly.txt', header=0)` - there is default separator `tab`. In `read_csv` is default separator `,`, so is necessary define `sep='\t'`

Comment: `df = dataset.drop('DATE', axis=1)` or `dataset.drop('DATE', axis=1, inplace=True)`

Comment: @steady_progress - you are welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So there are 2 problems:

First need change separator to `tab`, because [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) have default `sep=','` as commented @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ:

```
df = read_csv('USrealGDPGrowthPred_Quarterly.txt', header=0, sep='\t')
```

Or use [`read_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) with default `sep='\t'`:

```
df = df.read_table('USrealGDPGrowthPred_Quarterly.txt', header=0)
```

And then assign output back or use `inplace=True` in [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
dataset = dataset.drop('DATE', axis=1)
```

Or:

```
dataset.drop('DATE', axis=1, inplace=True)`
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue using `df.drop(columns=['column'])`

Adding The `inplace=True` to `df.drop(columns=['column'], inplace=True)` fixed it for me thank you!